# how to save camera capture images in nsuserdefaults in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, nsuserdefaults

I would like to save the camera capture images in nsuserdefaults. To add the camera capture images in collection view. (I added it in Cemeracaptureviewcontroler) my problem is: create one array and add the capture images collection view is working fine. but when I moving back to another view controller and come back again to Cemeracaptureviewcontroler then capture images are not display. In array values the images are display `null`. when the images save means that image array like this values.

```
<UIImage: 0x7ae93f50> size {640, 424} orientation 0 scale 1.000000">

<UIImage: 0x7ae93f52> size {640, 424} orientation 0 scale 1.000000">
```

So I think store the images in user defaults and display in collection. How can I solve this issues help me.

///here i get the capture image in picker

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
       UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
       imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
       imagePicker.delegate = self;
       imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
       [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

    originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    recipeImageView.image = [originalImage fixOrientation];

    [self.phto_arr_ addObject:originalImage];        
    [_collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Do not store images in NSUserDefaults. Write it to a file.

Comment: how to save as file sample code ple ?

Comment: @rmaddy is absolutely right! `NSUserDefault` is used to save preferences of your application. So it is more convenient that you should use it for light weight data. Storing array of images in `NSUserDefaults` is not a good way.

Comment: SO these days...Question 1. i want to shoot my foot  answerers 1.Shoot your with gun first point it to your foot and pull trigger.  No one says dont do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the images into NSUserDefults as,

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if(!self.phto_arr_){
         self.phto_arr_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.phto_arr_ addObject: chosenImage];
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.phto_arr_];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: encodedObject forKey:@"images"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

and retrieve as,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = (NSUserDefaults *)[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedObject = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"images"];
    self.phto_arr_ = (NSMutableArray *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
    [_collectionView reloadData];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: Application getting crash using this code?    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.phto_arr_ forKey:@"images"];
in this line not working

Comment: Sorry same error..as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key images   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "<UIImage: 0x79e413c0> size {638, 640} orientation 0 scale 1.000000"
) for key images'

Comment: NSKeyedArchiver is the better option. I would recommend saving images to local directory and accessing from that Path.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *browsed_Image = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage], 0.2)];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    if (browsed_Image) {
            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(browsed_Image) forKey:@"keyname"];
            });
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: how to implement this code in my didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo help me??

Comment: This code is for didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. Just change the NSUserderfaults "keyname" to your keyname. thats all. Image will be stored in NSUSerdefault.

Answer (score 0):

do not save images in defaults use..

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    UIImage  *image= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeStamp];
    NSString *fileName = nil;
    fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PICT_%@.png", [timeStampObj stringValue]];
    NSString *localFilePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [data writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      //if any UI task
          });
    });
}
```

datPath is  `dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"<your relevent subdirectoryname>"];`
now save the file path  "localFilePath" in array and use it you can maintain its persistance by keeping its retain count higher or simply save this array of file paths in `NSUserDefaults`

you can set image as

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:<localFilePath>]
```